# ejs include with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

With the code below, the contents of `car.ejs` appears properly.

```
<div id="carHolder">
    <%- include('car.ejs') %>            
</div>
```

Then I want to include multiple `car.ejs` dynamically, so I tried this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("carHolder").innerHTML += "<%- include('car.ejs') %>";
</script>
```

But there is still only one `car.ejs` appearing. I also tried with empty `div`:

```
<div id="carHolder"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("carHolder").innerHTML = "<%- include('car.ejs') %>";
</script>
```

Then there's no `car.ejs` appearing at all. How to dynamically include ejs with innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

`ejs` is a JavaScript library which allows you to render `.ejs` templates.
It must be rendered by the library.

A minimal example from their website ():

```js
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
<script>
  let people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];
  let html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
</script>
```

In line 4 you see how you can render `.ejs` content on the fly within the browser.
But I doubt that `include` will for for the browser version.

A possible solution would be to load the content of `car.ejs` into a variable beforehand and just render that instead.